# Project - Move issue from one column to another

Tags: github

## Overview:

I have created a Project under a GitHub repository and added some custom columns `Ready`, `In Progress` and `Done`

## Goal:

- I would like to move the issue from `Ready` to `In Progress` when a branch is created for that issue.
- Example: If I have an issue #10 in `Ready` and I create a branch from master called `#10-FixBug` then I would like issue #10 to move from `Ready` to `In Progress`.

## Questions:

- How would I be able to do this ?
- I don't see any built in automation preset for this, can I customise the project automation to achieve this goal ?
- Do I need to create a web hook ? (I was under the impression web hook is mainly for 3rd party tools.) If so how should I configure for GitHub to pick the event changes (is there a link?)

## Note:

- I am only using GitHub to manage my project, I am not using 3rd party tools such as Jira / Waffle or others

Comment: Just to be clear, [is that what you're talking about?](https://developer.github.com/v3/projects/columns/)

Comment: Partly yes, I am referring to the Project in that link, but I am looking at moving the issue from one column to another automatically when a branch is created. I just learned from the GitHub support that is not supported at the moment (not sure if it would be added in the future)

Answer (score 1):

Just heard from GitHub support that this is not currently supported. I have passed it as a feedback as nice to have.